# Laravel Eloquent Query Builder Performance issue

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I creating a wrapper function for Laravel Query Builder for creating dynamic query and not repeating same things.
My function is given below

```
Class Crud{
  public function get($tbl,$field,$where){
     $query = Capsule::table($tbl);
     if($where != null)  $query = $query->where($where);
     $query = $query->select($field);
     return $query;
  }
}
```

Function call

```
$crud = new Crud();
$field = ['a','b','c'];
$where = ['x' => 1];
$query = $crud->get('tbl',$field,$where);
```

**Question:**

Is this query slow down performence?

Why a single query executed multiple times like this?

```
Select * from tbl
Select * from tbl where (x = ?)
Select a,b,c from tbl where (x = ?)
```

Comment: what do you log and where do you see the log exactly ?

Comment: I use $query->toSql() and write it in a file of server

Comment: search for `prepared statements`

Comment: My question is not about prepared statements, my question why a single query executed 3 times?